# how can i find the data between the two different dates like (29-05-2021 to 08-06-2021) in MYSQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, date

i was write a mysql query to get the data between the two dates(ex: 29-05-2021 to 08-06-2021). but it shows the only current month(june) data only. it didn't show the (may) month data.

example:

**i was stored john at 30-05-2021, sam at 31-05-2021, raja at 07-06-2021, ramesh at 05-06-2021. When i was run the query only showed raja, ramesh. it's not show the john and sam.**

this is my mysql query

`SELECT staff_name FROM staff_info WHERE join_date <= '09-06-2021'`

**in database i was stored date in varchar method and format is d-m-Y**.

can any one help to solve these problem.

Comment: Dates should always be stored in a DATE datatype, then you dont get these issues

Comment: `in database i was stored date in varchar method`...well that's your first mistake. Dates are not strings (except when you are showing them to human beings). Use the `date` column type and your life will immediately get a lot easier.

Comment: Now you will have to convert your "bit of unknown text" into a proper date using [`str_to_date()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) So that proper date processing can take place

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to convert the text which only you know is a date to a date type so MySQL knows how it can process it easily as a date

[`str_to_date()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) is used to convert text into a Date type

```
SELECT staff_name 
FROM staff_info 
WHERE str_to_date(join_date, '%m/%d/%Y') between '2021-05-31' AND '2021-06-06'
```